# Blackberry app size issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-world

I am trying to develop a BlackBerry game and I'm facing several problems related to app-size (the game data needed for all levels and all characters has more than 20 MB size on disk)

I understood that the app size can't exceed 5 MB. Does anyone know if this limitation can be somehow avoided?

During my research, I found 2 solutions but I am not sure if these are allowed by RIM:

1. the game data to be separated by the game /application itself, in small packages under 5 MB. After user downloaded the game and lunched it, at a certain point in the game, packages will be downloaded, one by one,  from publisher's server or BlackBerry World (preferable), to device's memory or device's memory card. From here, the app can access the data anytime it's needed. I already tested by uploading resources to the device and it worked fine. I just need to know if this is allowed or not.
2. release 4 small games with the size under 5 MB each but share the profile, score from one application to another. I tested this method, too. and the result was OK for me.